# Событие нажатия на текст(android studio)

Tags: android, android-studio

можно ли создать событие при нажатие на текст, чтобы это работало по типу гиперссылки, но на другой лайаут?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328757/how-to-click-or-tap-on-a-textview-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Варианты - открыть ссылку в браузере

```
    <TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
android:text="your text"
android:autoLink="web" />
```

Если хотите кастомную схему которая будет перехватываться другой activity например  com.package.name

```
<intent-filter>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="com.package.name" />  
</intent-filter>
```

А в ссылку зашиваете:

```
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href='com.package.name://action-to-perform/id-that-might-be-needed/'>Title</a>"));
```

Затем в активити можно сделать так:

```
Uri data = getIntent().getData();
```

Но проще всего конечно сделать:

```
android:onClick="editActions" 
android:clickable="true"

public void clickActions(View view){

          startActivity(new Intent(this, com.package.name.Activity.class);

    }
```